# PostrgeSQL: как написать двойной SELECT - параметр из первого на вход второму?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с запросом.
Имеется две таблицы - `city(id, name)`, `country(id, name, city)`.
Нужно для каждой записи из таблицы `city` подсчитать ее количество в таблице `country` (то есть найти в таблице стран (`country`): сколько раз встречается каждый город(`city`)). При этом на выходе нужно получить таблицу городов: все параметры города (`id, name`) и его рейтинг (сколько раз он встретился в таблице `country`).

Пробовал `SELECT COUNT(country.city) FROM country INNER JOIN city ON country.city=city.id` - для вывода рейтинга города, но выводится количество всех записей, где города совпали, а нужно количество совпадений для каждого города в отдельности.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: я не понял, у вас в таблице стран вообще id не PK ??  или в стране только один город?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для каждой записи, то внешнее соединение:

```
SELECT
    city.name, COUNT(country.city) 
FROM country 
RIGHT JOIN city 
    ON country.city=city.id 
GROUP BY city.id, city.name
```

Comment: А как сделать такой запрос по нескольким полям таблицы city?
Если бы к названию города добавили еще численность населения `people_count`, как вывести количество записей `city.name city.people_count` в таблице `country`?

Comment: ну бери любые поля из city, добавляя их в group by

Comment: Ivan, спасибо!!